# Error in write.table

Tags: r, write.table

```
 for(i in 1:4){
     write.table(x, file=cat("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\example_",i,sep=""),row.names=FALSE)}
```

> Error in if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { : 
>     argument is of length zero

How can I solve this error?? What are the differences between `write.table`, `write.csv` and `write.csv2` ??

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste()` or `paste0()` instead of `cat()` should resolve the issue you are having, as mentioned in the comment.

`write.table()` creates a dataframe

`write.csv()` uses "." for the decimal point and a comma for the separator.

`write.csv2()` uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon for the separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in some Western European locales.

read `?write.table` for more details than what is in the answer I gave above.

I thought I might add a bit more to explain why `cat()` will not work.

if you look in the routine for `cat()` you will see that this is meant for sending output to stdout or some file connection.

```
function (..., file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL, 
    append = FALSE) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) 
        if (file == "") 
            file <- stdout()
        else if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") {
            file <- pipe(substring(file, 2L), "w")
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
        else {
            file <- file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
            on.exit(close(file))
        }
    .Internal(cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append))
}
```

so, when `cat` is run it is sending its output to stdout in your case not back to the function calling it (`write.table()`).